# Is there a word for describing the shoulder and/or neck pain caused by bad sleep postures?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

There is a simple word in my native tongue for this symptom but it is somehow hard to find a corresponding term in English despite how common this type of pain occurs in our daily life.

Comment: http://onelook.com/?w=crick&ls=a

Comment: If the pain is 'acute' – sudden and intense – it's called a crick in the neck, facet syndrome or muscular rheumatism.

http://www.netdoctor.co.uk/diseases/facts/neckpains.htm#ixzz2SCzwWDSJ

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not every concept has a corresponding word but it turns out that this one does.

> [crick](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crick)

is an informal term meaning a persistent joint/muscle  pain in the neck or upper back usually due to holding an uncomfortable posture for too long.

> I have a **crick** in my neck from falling asleep in the airplane seat.

Comment: You should have voted to close this for 1. No background effort. 2. GR. 3. Too localized (shoulder + neck + bad-sleep-posture makes it a technically involved term). BTW *Crick* does not cover the three criteria adequately.

Comment: @Kris: I can see a case for all three of your criteria buy still disagree. But I'm curious, how does 'crick' _not_ cover the OP?

Comment: See my comment @OP: "If the pain is 'acute' – sudden and intense – it's called a crick in the neck," -- Only an acute pain, (& ?only in the neck); still qualified with 'in the neck,' not by itself. *Crick* does not seem relate to shoulder-pain. Etiology is not covered, it could be caused by anything. It's a *very loosely defined term*.

Comment: @Kris: of sure it is loosely defined; it is not formal technical medical vocabulary. But I think it answers directly the OP's question ('simple word', 'common...type of pain').

Answer (score 0):

**[Stiffness](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stiffness)**

You can have either a *stiff* shoulder, a *stiff* neck or a stiffness that is felt simultaneously in both parts of the body.

> 2) a. Not moving or operating easily or freely; resistant: *a stiff hinge*.
>   b. Lacking ease or comfort of movement; not limber: *a stiff neck*.